# reading the eobjects from the ecore file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have the ecore file which contains the class eobjects.Now i want to read that ecore file and get all the class eobjects from that ecore file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to reload your specific xmi file with a custom suffix?

Here is an example of a method that loads an ecore file at a specific location (path) and returns your root EObject

```
public static EObject loadYourModel(String path) {
    /*Initialzie Models*/
    YourPackage.eINSTANCE.eClass();

    /*register your xmi resources*/
    final Resource.Factory.Registry reg = Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
    final Map<String, Object> m = reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap();
    /*put all your different ecore file suffixes in the map; suffix = YourPackage.eNAME*/
    m.put(YourPackage.eNAME, new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
    /*you can put all different package names here*/

    /*Create a new Resource set to store the EObjects from the file*/
    ResourceSet resSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

    /*get the resource of your ecore file*/
    Resource resource = resSet.getResource(URI.createURI(path), true);
    /*Get the first element = root of your model hierachy*/
    EObject root = resource.getContents().get(0);
    return root;
}
```