# Is it possible to get value of an EReference by name?

Tags: emf

I want to get the value of the EReference from a Java program

I use this library: https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor

Here is an example of xmi file generated :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<graph:GModel xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:graph="http://de.tesis.dynaware.grapheditor.model/1.0">
  <nodes type="tree-node" x="1217.0" y="556.0">
    <connectors type="tree-output" connections="//@connections.0 //@connections.1" connectionDetachedOnDrag="false"/>
  </nodes>
  <nodes type="tree-node" x="1020.0" y="756.0">
    <connectors type="tree-input" connections="//@connections.0"/>
    <connectors type="tree-output" connectionDetachedOnDrag="false"/>
  </nodes>
  <nodes type="tree-node" x="1260.0" y="775.0">
    <connectors type="tree-input" connections="//@connections.1"/>
    <connectors type="tree-output" connectionDetachedOnDrag="false"/>
  </nodes>
  <connections type="tree-connection" source="//@nodes.0/@connectors.0" target="//@nodes.1/@connectors.0"/>
  <connections type="tree-connection" source="//@nodes.0/@connectors.0" target="//@nodes.2/@connectors.0"/>
</graph:GModel>
```

What i want is to get the value of the EReference source, and i must get for exemple : /@nodes.0/@connectors.0

I tried the code below

```
GModel gModel=model;
      EList<GConnection> connections=gModel.getConnections();
      for(GConnection connection : connections)
      {
          GConnector source=connection.getSource();
          System.out.println(" valeur source =" +source);
      }
```

but i obtain the result below :

valeur source=de.tesis.dynaware.grapheditor.model.impl.GConnectorImpl@21dd34be (id: null, type: tree-output, x: 0.0, y: 0.0, connectionDetachedOnDrag: false)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. `/@nodes.0/@connectors.0` is the cross reference to the first connector Object in the first node Object in the tree, therefore the `source` reference should retrieve it correctly.... Or do you want to actually retrieve the String value `/@nodes.0/@connectors.0` ? Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

After I read it again I suppose I understood your question.
You're trying to get the actual `EObject` at a specific location eg: `//@nodes.0/@connectors.0`?
This path is called the URIfragment. With an URIfragment you can get the EObject which is stored at this position from the root of the resource tree.
You need to put your `GModel`in an emf org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource, if does not have one yet (you can check `gModel.eResource()`)

Suppose `gModel.eResource() == null`:

```
//create a new Resource
Resource resource = new ResourceImpl();
//add the gModel
resource.getContents().add(gModel);
//get the EObject from the URIfragment
GConnector connector = (GConnector)resource.getEObject("//@nodes.0/@connectors.0");

assert resource.getURIFragment(connector).equals("//@nodes.0/@connectors.0");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What i want is to get the URIfragment.

Comment: Is ot possible to get this : //@nodes.0/@connectors.0 as a String?

Comment: `resource.getURIFragment(EObject eObject)` returns the URI fragment as String (The path in the containment tree to the eObject)

Comment: Yes it works. But in my file xmi above, I use : final URI fileUri = URI.createFileURI(absolutePath), if I want to generate only the id of the node, here (0), how can i process ? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to parse the XMI file to EObjects?

Comment: have a look at [how to read eobjects from a ecore file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38249127/6242846) you can combine this, first load the EObject tree from the file and then you can use the resource to get the specific EObject from your uri fragment